# result of a modal form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, modal-dialog

I create a form 'frmX' and i call it as a modal form :

```
res = frmX.ShowDialog()
```

This form has 3 buttons, Abort(**3**), Retry(**4**) and Ignore(**5**), but when the form opens, all the buttons on the first click return **2**.

I don't know why this occurs--all of the buttons has their property DialogResult right.

```
*Private Sub btnIgnorar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnIgnorar.Click
    btnIgnorar.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ignore
End Sub
Private Sub btnAbortar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAbortar.Click
    btnAbortar.DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort
End Sub
Private Sub btnReintentar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReintentar.Click
    btnReintentar.DialogResult = DialogResult.Retry
End Sub*
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that you set the DialogResult of the buttons. You must set the DialogResult of the form !

You actually have more than one option.

**Option 1 : Set the Form.DialogResult**

```
Private Sub btnIgnorar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnIgnorar.Click
    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ignore
End Sub
Private Sub btnAbortar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAbortar.Click
    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort
End Sub
Private Sub btnReintentar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReintentar.Click
    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Retry
End Sub
```

**Option 2 : Set the Button.DialogResult**

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponents()
    'Your init code here
    '...
    'By setting the buttons DialogResults, you don't even have to handle the click events
    btnIgnorar.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ignore
    btnAbortar.DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort
    btnReintentar.DialogResult = DialogResult.Retry
End Sub

'However, if you need to do some stuff before closing the form, you can
Private Sub btnAbortar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAbortar.Click
    'Do some stuff
    'You don't need the following line, as it will be done implicitly
    'Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks SuperPeanut! That's it!

Comment: The problem is rather that he sets `DialogResult` when the button is _clicked_. The button will automatically set the form's dialog result to the dialog result of the button _if it's determined before the click event is called_.

Comment: @VisualVincent I don't understand what you mean. The `Me` here references to the form. So the form sets its `DialogResult` when any of the buttons is clicked.

Comment: Yes, but I was referring to the buttons' DialogResult. His code would have worked too if he didn't set the DialogResult in the click event, but for example in the Form Load event. My point was just that buttons have a DialogResult because they will automatically set the form's result when clicked, but only if the property was set _before_ a button is clicked.

Comment: Oh OK... I forgot about that actually... I'll update my answer

Comment: @VisualVincent Answer updated. Does it look clear ? Will OP be informed that the answer was updated ?

Answer (score 2):

Could do with seeing a bit more context, but the following should do what I think you want:

```
Private Sub btnIgnorar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnIgnorar.Click
    DialogResult = DialogResult.Ignore
    Close
End Sub
```

This will close the dialog and return the associated result code to the caller. As to the original code, it seems a bit strange setting the values in the buttons click handlers?